# how do we check similarity between hash values of two audio files in python?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, computer-vision, similarity

About the data :
we have 2 video files which are same and audio of these files is also same but they differ in quality.
that is one is in 128kbps and 320kbps respectively.

we have used ffmpeg to extract the audio from video, and generated the hash values for both the audio file using the code : **ffmpeg -loglevel error -i 320kbps.wav -map 0 -f hash -**
the output was : **SHA256=4c77a4a73f9fa99ee219f0019e99a367c4ab72242623f10d1dc35d12f3be726c**
similarly we did it for another audio file to which we have to compare ,
**C:\FFMPEG>ffmpeg -loglevel error -i 128kbps.wav -map 0 -f hash -**
**SHA256=f8ca7622da40473d375765e1d4337bdf035441bbd01187b69e4d059514b2d69a**

Now we know that these audio files and hash values are different but we want to know how much different/similar they are actually , for eg: like some distance in  a-b is say 3

can someone help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cryptographic hashes like SHA-256 cannot be used to compare the distance between two audio files. Cryptographic hashes are deliberately designed to be unpredictable and to ideally reveal no information about the input that was hashed.

However, there are many suitable [**acoustic fingerprinting**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) algorithms that accept a segment of audio and return a fingerprint vector. Then, you can measure the similarity of two audio clips by seeing how close together their corresponding fingerprint vectors are.

## Picking an acoustic fingerprinting algorithm

[Chromaprint](https://acoustid.org/chromaprint) is a popular open source acoustic fingerprinting algorithm with [bindings and reimplementations](https://github.com/acoustid/chromaprint#related-projects) in many popular languages. Chromaprint is used by the [AcoustID](https://acoustid.org/) project, which is building an open source database to collect fingerprints and metadata for popular music.

The researcher Joren Six has also written and open-sourced the acoustic fingerprinting libraries [Panako](https://github.com/JorenSix/Panako) and [Olaf](https://github.com/JorenSix/Olaf). However, they are currently both licensed as AGPLv3 and might possibly infringe upon still-active US patents.

Several companies--such as [Pex](https://pex.com/)--sell APIs for checking if arbitrary audio files contain copyrighted material. If you sign up for Pex, they will give you [their closed-source SDK](https://docs.ae.pex.com/py/fingerprinting.html) for generating acoustic fingerprints as per their algorithm.

## Generating and comparing fingerprints

Here, I will assume that you chose Chromaprint. You will have to install libchromaprint and an FFT library.

I will assume that you chose Chromaprint and that you want to compare fingerprints using Python, although the general principle applies to other fingerprinting libraries.

1. Install [libchromaprint or the fpcalc command line tool](https://acoustid.org/chromaprint).
2. Install the [pyacoustid](https://pypi.org/project/pyacoustid/) Python library from PyPI. It will look for your existing installation of libchromaprint or fpcalc.
3. Normalize your audio files to remove differences that could confuse Chromaprint, such as silence at the beginning of an audio file. Also keep in mind that Chromaprin
4. While I typically [measure the distance between vectors using NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), many Chromaprint users compare two audio files by computing the `xor` function between the fingerprints and counting the number of `1` bits.

Here is some quick-and-dirty Python code for comparing the distance between two fingerprints. Although if I were building a production service, I'd implement the comparison in C++ or Rust.

```py
from operator import xor
from typing import List

# These imports should be in your Python module path
# after installing the `pyacoustid` package from PyPI.
import acoustid
import chromaprint


def get_fingerprint(filename: str) -> List[int]:
    """
    Reads an audio file from the filesystem and returns a
    fingerprint.

    Args:
        filename: The filename of an audio file on the local
            filesystem to read.

    Returns:
        Returns a list of 32-bit integers. Two fingerprints can
        be roughly compared by counting the number of
        corresponding bits that are different from each other.
    """
    _, encoded = acoustid.fingerprint_file(filename)
    fingerprint, _ = chromaprint.decode_fingerprint(
        encoded
    )
    return fingerprint


def fingerprint_distance(
    f1: List[int],
    f2: List[int],
    fingerprint_len: int,
) -> float:
    """
    Returns a normalized distance between two fingerprints.

    Args:
        f1: The first fingerprint.

        f2: The second fingerprint.

        fingerprint_len: Only compare the first `fingerprint_len`
            integers in each fingerprint. This is useful
            when comparing audio samples of a different length.

    Returns:
        Returns a number between 0.0 and 1.0 representing
        the distance between two fingerprints. This value
        represents distance as like a percentage.
    """
    max_hamming_weight = 32 * fingerprint_len
    hamming_weight = sum(
        sum(
            c == "1"
            for c in bin(xor(f1[i], f2[i]))
        )
        for i in range(fingerprint_len)
    )
    return hamming_weight / max_hamming_weight
```

The above functions would let you compare two fingerprints as follows:

```py
>>> f1 = get_fingerprint("1.mp3")
>>> f2 = get_fingerprint("2.mp3")
>>> f_len = min(len(f1), len(f2))
>>> fingerprint_distance(f1, f2, f_len)
0.35 # for example
```

You can read more about how to use Chromaprint to compute the distance between different audio files. [This mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/g/acoustid/c/Uq_ASjaq3bw/m/kLreyQgxKmgJ) describes the theory of how to compare Chromaprint fingerprints. [This GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/lalinsky/1132166) offers another implementation.

Comment: Since the question uses the ffmpeg tag it's worth mentioning that ffmpeg has a [chromaprint](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#chromaprint-1) muxer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a SHA256 hash for this. This is intentional. It would weaken the security of the hash if you could. what you suggest is akin to differential cryptoanalysis. SHA256 is a modern cryptographic hash, and designed to be safe against such attacks.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question, and may be more appropriate as a comment instead.