# How to calculate similarity between two voice files of different lengths with python?

Tags: python, record, similarity, voice, librosa

I'd like to compare two voice files.
The first file(ref) and the comparison file(comp) are pronounced by different person, respectively.
My hypothesis is that the closer the speech similarity is, the same pronunciation, intonation, and tone will be.
However, the problem is that the two files have different lengths. Is it possible to compare?

```
!pip install librosa     # colab

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa
import librosa.display

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))

x_1, fs_1 = librosa.load('voice_tar.wav')
x_2, fs_2 = librosa.load('voice_comp.wav')

print('<Voice_tar>', 'audio shape:', x_1.shape, 'length:', x_1.shape[0]/float(fs_1), 'secs')
print('<Voice_comp>', 'audio shape:', x_2.shape, 'length:', x_2.shape[0]/float(fs_2), 'secs')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
librosa.display.waveshow(x_1, sr=fs_1, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set(title='Voice_tar')
ax[0].label_outer()

librosa.display.waveshow(x_2, sr=fs_2, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set(title='Voice_comp')
```

The results are as follows.
<Voice_tar> audio shape: (43395,) length: 1.9680272108843537 secs
<Voice_comp> audio shape: (31673,) length: 1.4364172335600907 secs

This is the image of 2 voice files.
[image of 2 voice files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAkDW.png)

And, how can I get similarity with ibrosa.segment.cross_similarity()?

Comment: Are the two persons saying the same phrase? Is the phrase aligned?

Comment: Did you fin d the solution? Can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

I am studying about this problem, too; it is better to process audio directly but there is still no solution above, you can try converting this to computer vision with image problem, as below

1. read 2 audios, write their features into 2 images, example

   ```
   x, sr = librosa.load(duongdan)

   if show:
       librosa.display.waveshow(y_ref, sr=sr1, alpha=0.4)
       plt.show()

   fea = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(y=x, sr=sr)[0]  # or any feature you want
   frames = range(len(fea))  # Computing the time variable for visualization
   t = librosa.frames_to_time(frames)
   plt.plot(t, fea, color='b')
   ```
2. calculate similarity between these two images, use phash as https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/ or https://github.com/thorn-oss/perception; or I have thought about histogram but haven't done anything yet

Have you tried this [how do we check similarity between hash values of two audio files in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953484/how-do-we-check-similarity-between-hash-values-of-two-audio-files-in-python?rq=3) and this https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.segment.cross_similarity.html#librosa.segment.cross_similarity